# How can we add MetaTags to a Spartacus Storefront

Tags: typescript, meta-tags, spartacus-storefront

I am looking for a solution to add metatags to a spartacus storefront.
Tags like meta description,title, robots, canonical.
If anyone can suggest how this can be done.

Comment: Please add code and explain what you have done and what are you facing issue with , stack overflow is not a place to get ready made answers

Comment: @Abhishake were you able to do it. I am facing similar issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all information you need are included in [documentation](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/html-tags/#customizing-meta-tags). Otherwise, state what exactly you are having a problem with.

Comment: Hi Michal Thank you for the document. I figured out most meta tags are OOTB in spartacus. Could you provide me an example how can I use canonical tags in spartacus.

Comment: Please see example: https://github1s.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/HEAD/feature-libs/checkout/core/services/checkout-page-meta.resolver.ts

Comment: Thank you Michal!! It was really helpful for me.